# Django Rest Framework nested relationship sets field 'read_only=True'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My `AirportSerializer` has a field `city`, that is a `ForeignField` nested by setting `depth=1`. I need the serializer to return the information of the 'Airport' and the information of the related 'City', so I need to nest the objects. The problem is that the field 'city' is set `read_only=True` when I set the depth to 1, so `post` method raises a 'not null' error because the field is required.

I tried by setting `city = CitySerializer()`, and I get the nested result that I need, but this approach implies that a `post` method expects data for creating a new 'Airport' and a new 'City' also. This is not what I want. I only want the field 'city' not to be set `read_only=True`.

The [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) says that I have to

> create `create()` and/or `update()` methods in order to explicitly
>   specify how the child relationships should be saved

I tried this, with this serializer:

```
class AirportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Airport
        fields = ('id', 'city', 'name', 'iata')
        depth = 1

    def create(self, validated_data):
        airport = models.Airport.objects.create(**validated_data)

        return airport
```

But `validated_data` gets de 'city' field already set to `null`, so `airport = models.Airport.objects.create(**validated_data)` raises the same `not null` error.

So, in the end, I created the `create()` model following the documentation, but the 'city' field remains 'read_only'.

I have expended almost all day trying to find a way for the serializer to return a nested 'city' without setting the field 'city' `read_only` and without enforcing the creation of a new instance of 'City' in the process.

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested serializition is tricky, there is some ambiguity with defining the Serializer with whether you want to create or set the nested objects. I've handled it in different ways.

1. Just use foreign keys, you will make the front end make to http
   requests for the data but in the end this is the most idiomatic way
   of doing it.
2. Use CitySerializer in the AirportSerializer -- let that one be read
   only. Have a write only city_id field that relates just the ID
       on writing.
3. Use different serializers, one with CitySerializer and one with the just the id, decide which one to do in the view's `get_serializer_class` method
4. Use the CitySerializer and then get the city you want it set as in the create() method.

Example:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
     city = City.objects.get(get_city_somehow(self.context['request']))
     airport = models.Airport.objects.create(city=city, **validated_data)
```